# Recording audio from amplifier to mobile

Tags: recording, amplifiers, microphones, audio

I wanna record audio from an amplifier ([this](https://www.ahujaradios.com/amplifiers-2/high-power-pa-amplifiers/ssa-10000.html)) via android phone. I have a 6.3mm trs and 3.5mm trrs jack. I wanna know how to wiring them for recording purposes. For example: 6.3mm left and right channel to 3.5mm mic or 6.3mm left/right channel to 3.5mm mic. Which way is the best and safe or any other suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile"? A phone? Presumably, one with 3.5mm input? As I think you're aware, a phone 3.5mm connection usually has only mono channel for the mic. There are a number of devices on the market that use a data port (usb, lightning) to record in stereo...

Comment: @AndyBonner yes, android phone. if i use 3.5mm, should i shorted left and right channel to mic or only one left/right to mic?

Comment: @AndyBonner - A 'mobile' is what we Brits* call what you guys call a 'cellphone'. [yet another transpondian mis-match ;) [*& from context, Indian English uses the Brit term rather than the US]

Comment: While this would technically be possible you’d have huge limitations:
You can only do Mono, and the microphone input probably expects a low level signal. The sensible way to go would probably to get a cheap USB sound card with line in and standard USB audio driver. You can connect that to your phone via USB.